# Comparator vs Error amplifier vs OP-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, error-amplifier

Could you do me a favor? It is my first time to use "StackExchange".
I wonder the different point of these three components.

Comparator vs Error amplifier vs Op-amp (and OTA)

As I found they are all have similar circuit structure which is "differential amplifier".
So I think the difference point is just amount of gain, feedback and any spec(BW...)
Could you please let me know about these component in detail?
Or It will be helpful if you share any document or textbook.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

These are components (not functions); may be used for many functions:

- Comparator: a component; analog in, digital out (a logic level)
- Op-amp: a component; analog in, analog out (a voltage)
- OTA: a component; analog in, analog out (a current)

This is a function (not a component); may use a variety of components (including possibly an op-amp)

- Error amplifier: compares two values: 1) a desired reference; 2) the actual value. Then, produces an output that is proportional to the difference between the two values. (It may also be the differential or integral of the difference.)